# RCP exception with Gemini Blueprint

Tags: eclipse-rcp, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I am getting this kind of error (see below). I am suspecting some plugins are missing (perhaps transitive dependencies) but I am not sure. What's more: what does this **.source** suffix mean?

Can someone help me please?

Regards,

Julien.

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.556
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../jeanbaptistemartin.com/java/desktop/jbm-gestionnaire/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text.source_3.7.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.source_5.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.source_1.1.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.security.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.source_3.5.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.557
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.core.linux.source_3.2.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.source_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.httpinvoker.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.ui.graph.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views.source_3.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.autowire.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.558
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor.source_1.0.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.559
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.662
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.662
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.663
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.663
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.663
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation.source_1.2.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.664
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.source_1.0.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.664
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor.source_1.0.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.665
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.source_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.665
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.665
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.666
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse.source_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.666
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.source_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.667
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ql.source_2.0.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.667
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.source_1.1.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.667
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.668
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools.source_2.0.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.668
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.source_2.1.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.source_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport.source_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.source_1.0.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.source_1.0.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.source_2.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.669
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatechecker.source_1.1.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.source_3.4.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry.source_3.5.101.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.security.source_1.1.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui.source_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.670
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.source_1.0.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.util.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.appserver.source_3.1.400.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.help.source_3.5.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.databinding.source_1.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text.source_3.7.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jsch.core.source_1.1.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jsch.ui.source_1.1.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.671
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.source_3.5.201.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.source_3.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi.services.source_3.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi.source_3.7.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi.util.source_3.2.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.platform.source_3.7.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.rcp.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.search.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.672
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86.source_3.7.1.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core.source_3.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui.source_3.6.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.text.source_3.5.101.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.browser.source_3.3.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.source_3.4.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.console.source_3.5.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.673
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.source_3.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms.source_3.5.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.application.source_1.0.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.source_3.4.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.source_3.2.500.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.source_3.4.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.source_3.5.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.674
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.net.source_1.2.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.presentations.r21.source_3.2.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.source_3.5.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.views.source_3.6.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.compatibility.source_3.2.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.source_3.7.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.675
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.configurator.source_3.3.100.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.core.linux.source_3.2.200.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.core.source_3.2.500.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.scheduler.source_3.2.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.update.ui.source_3.2.300.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.aop.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.asm.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.batch.core.source_2.0.2.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.676
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.beans.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.binding.source_2.0.7.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.context.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.context.support.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.core.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.expression.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.faces.source_2.0.7.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ajdt.ui.visualiser.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.677
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ajdt.ui.xref.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.core.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.mylyn.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.ui.matcher.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.aop.ui.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.batch.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.autowire.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.mylyn.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.678
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.autowire.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.editor.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.graph.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.refactoring.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.search.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.integration.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.679
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.mylyn.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.security.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.core.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.mylyn.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.680
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.webflow.ui.editor.source_2.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.681
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle 
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.osgi.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.682
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.rmi.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.682
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.security.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.682
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.682
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.stream.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.udp.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.ws.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.integration.xml.source_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.jdbc.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.jms.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.js.source_2.0.7.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.orm.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.oxm.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.683
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.security.annotation.source_2.0.5.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.security.core.source_2.0.5.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.transaction.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.web.servlet.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.web.source_3.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.webflow.source_2.0.7.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.ws.source_1.5.8.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.springframework.xml.source_1.5.8.
!SUBENTRY 2 jbm-gestionnaire 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.684
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.jeanbaptistemartin.jbm-domain_2.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.685
!MESSAGE Bundle com.jeanbaptistemartin.jbm-domain_2.0.0 [9] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.jeanbaptistemartin.jbm-domain 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.685
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.hibernate.annotations_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.685
!MESSAGE Bundle org.springframework.instrument.tomcat_3.0.6.RELEASE [424] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.springframework.instrument.tomcat 2 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.685
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.catalina.loader_[6.0.16,7.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-15 17:24:11.686
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "jbm-gestionnaire" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/julien/Documents/jeanbaptistemartin.com/java/desktop/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/jbm-gestionnaire.product/1323966248656.log.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle `jbm-gestionnaire` will not resolve because it has many missing dependencies. However the dependencies appear to be bogus... you should never have to depend on source bundles. Check the MANIFEST.MF of `jbm-gestionnaire` and remove the spurious dependencies from the `Require-Bundle` section.

Comment: Neil, thanks. I work with Eclipse RCP. Do you know of a good way to resolve dependencies? Can I use Maven for instance? I have spent the best of the day battling with dependency problems. Do you have tips as to how to deal with large amounts of dependencies? Regards. Julien